# Nginx w/ 2 Symfony installations can't use separate databases

Tags: symfony, nginx, environment-variables

Running a single nginx instance on a V-Server I want to have two separate Symfony installations:

The first installation is running a few month now, the second was installed recently and is publicly accessible, **BUT it uses the database connection of the first one when handling it via console!**

### Nginx

#### symfony1.conf

```
...
location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
        fastcgi_param APP_SECRET XXX;
        fastcgi_param DATABASE_URL "mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony1_db";
    ...
}
...
```

#### symfony2.conf

```
...
location ~ ^/index\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_param APP_ENV prod;
        fastcgi_param APP_SECRET XXX;
        fastcgi_param DATABASE_URL "mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony2_db";
    ...
}
...
```

When I try to create the schema for the **second** installation (`php /var/www/html/smyfony2/bin/console doctrine:database:create`, it gives me this error:

> Could not create database `symfony1_db` for connection named default

My idea was to change the

`fastcgi_param DATABASE_URL "mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony2_db";`

to

`fastcgi_param DATABASE_URL_2 "mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony2_db";`

but

- is that necessary?
- is that even possible?
- where would I have to tell that to my Symfony installation

Any hint is highly appreciated.

#### Clarification:

Everything works fine when I access the site via browser, it's just confusing sth in my console.

Comment: I may be wrong, but those `fastcgi_*` params apply only for, well, FastCGI requests. The one you are attempting to invoke is pure command line. In addition, your question suggests that you have two vhosts where both target the same instance of Symfony (not separate ones), right?

Answer (score 1):

Your nginx configuration is not applied if you invoke the `console` command in your terminal and therefore has nothing to do with your problem.

You can solve this problem by adding the `symfony/dotenv` package to your application.

```
composer require symfony/dotenv
```

Then enable the component inside your `bin/console` file:

```
(new Dotenv())->load(__DIR__.'/../.env');
```

Now create two  `.env` files with the correct database parameters/environment-variables in the root folder of both of your applications.

```
# .env
DATABASE_URL='mysql://user:password@127.0.0.1:3306/symfony2_db'
```

Further you could use tool like [direnv](https://direnv.net) to load different environment variables environment dependening on your shell's current working directory.

Comment: Very good answer. Side note to OP: Symfony 4.2 just rolled out ability to have multiple dotenv files, but this may not be applicable to your case. More info here: https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-4-2-define-env-vars-per-environment